# formating a hard drive for use in an asus aspire one d250

Tags: windows-xp, netbook

I have an Asus Aspire One D250 that's out of warranty and whose hard drive is giving the click of death.  I'm trying to use a spare SATA HDD I have but am having some difficulty.

I have a USB CD drive that I plugged into the computer but when I tried to boot off of a Windows XP SP3 install CD the hard drive wasn't recognized.

I tried to format the hard drive in another computer and then plug the hard drive into the Asus Aspire and although this gets me to the Windows XP loading screen it crashes before it gets into Windows, itself.  Even in Safe Mode.

I also tried to install Windows XP off of a USB stick but it seemed to hang during the install process.  As in the next day it was still in the blue screen installer.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you perform a sanity check on the drive at all? Not Microsoft's chkdsk worthless program, more of a low level disk diagnostic? Every HD manufacturer have one for download. Moreover, Hiren's boot CD is a good friend in that matter.

Answer (score 1):

It could help to go into the BIOS and put the SATA port in IDE (or PATA) compatibility mode.  You can then switch it back to Native mode once XP is installed.  I don't know how to do this specifically for the Aspire One, but this has worked for me in the past when trying to install XP on other SATA systems.